# TypeScript: is there an interface for array-like object?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I know that I have array like `['string', 10, true];`. Is there a way to write an interface for it? I know there's globally indexed interface:

```
interface IEntry {
    [i:number]:string;
}
```

But typing the following is not working:

```
interface IEntry {
    [0]:string;
    [1]:number;
    [2]:boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Typescript tuples.

```
type Entry: [string, number, boolean];

var entry: Entry = ['foo', 1, false]; 
var exit: Entry = ['bar']; // tsc error
```

Comment: Spec at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#333-tuple-types